# 301 http to https I have tried everything

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have tried all the answers on all support forums, tried for hours and soon starting to cry. Please help me.

I just want to 301 ALL http to https. The whole site should go under HTTPS if a user type in http it should 301 to https. This is my htaccess file.

Now I only get loops or servererrors.

This i the working htaccess before i tried anything:

```
    # BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -F
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple conditions to check if rewrite is on and only need RewriteEngine on once. Put the https redirect at the top of the rules. See if this works for you.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Redirect to https.
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

   # BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -F
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
    # END W3TC Page Cache core
    # BEGIN WordPress
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: First of, thank you for talking the time to help me. :)

So If I get you right I could just talke the code you gave me and replace my old? 

You leave this part out: 
# END W3TC Page Cache core
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

However.

When I just use the code you gave me I get the same error:
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Use the code as it is that I gave you and also make sure to clear your browser cache or try a different browser and see if it works.

Comment: Put this code I gave you under `# END W3TC Browser Cache`

Comment: Thank you. I have now tried to do as you are saying. still got the same error. I have tried different browsers and from different computers on diffrent IP. it is the site https://xn--bsta-kreditkortet-qqb.nu/ .

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you. The code should work. Are you sure your htaccess is being read? Take everything else out of your htaccess and leave the two lines I added and see what happens? Also intentionally add some random text to the htaccess file. If it returns and error like 500 server error. then it's being read by the server.

Comment: Tried to take everything out except your two lines of code but still get redirect loop. What I haven’t mentioned is that I am using a plugin called “WordPress https” to exclude links and images that are http:// from the website. Anyhow, I tried to deactivate this plugin and then added your complete code from your first answer - suddenly the sites http://xn--bsta-kreditkortet-qqb.nu/ and bästa-kreditkortet.nu worked but everything with “www” wasn’t working. 5 minutes later everything returned to redirect loops once again. Any tips on how to proceed?